# Using DataTables in Laravel without aJax - No data available in table

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datatables

I have a regular Laravel view that renders a table. When I try to use Datatables on it, it does render the table but it seems to want to format it before the table is actually rendered. I'm confused because, by the time the view is rendered, the server-side work is already done. The only thing it's doing is to render the table with the object passed from the controller.

```html
<table id="stockmovement" class="table table-hover" style="width:100%">
  <tbody>
    <thead>
      <th>Material</th>
      <th>Tipo</th>
      <th>Quantidade</th>
      <th>Valor total</th>
      <th>Data</th>
      <th>Ordem</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </thead>
    @foreach($ordercontents as $ordercontent)
      <tr>
        <td>{{ $ordercontent->material_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $ordercontent->type }}</td>
        <td>{{ $ordercontent->oc_weight }}</td>
        <td>{{ number_format($ordercontent->oc_weight * $ordercontent->material_price, 2) }}</td>
        <td>{{ $ordercontent->order_date }}</td>
        <td>{{ $ordercontent->order_name }}</td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#stockmovement').DataTable(); 
})
```

This is what I end up with:

[image]

I don't want to use AJAX to form my table. I've used plenty of vanilla PHP and DataTables instances before where it works just fine. I would appreciate any pointers on what I may be missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have placed `<tbody>` in the wrong place. `<tbody>` should use under the `</thead>`.

Here is the code example:

```
<table id="stockmovement" class="table table-hover" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <th>Material</th>
      <th>Tipo</th>
      <th>Quantidade</th>
      <th>Valor total</th>
      <th>Data</th>
      <th>Ordem</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($ordercontents as $ordercontent)
      <tr>
        <td>{{ $ordercontent->material_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $ordercontent->type }}</td>
        <td>{{ $ordercontent->oc_weight }}</td>
        <td>{{ number_format($ordercontent->oc_weight * $ordercontent->material_price, 2) }}</td>
        <td>{{ $ordercontent->order_date }}</td>
        <td>{{ $ordercontent->order_name }}</td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I should remember that almost every time that Datatables doesn't do what you want it's because of a mal-formed table (it expects all the elements in the right place). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add `tr` tag inside the `thead` tag.
The foreach loop should be in the opening and closing `tbody` tag.

It should look like this:

```
<table id="stockmovement" class="table table-hover" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Material</th>
            <th>Tipo</th>
            <th>Quantidade</th>
            <th>Valor total</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Ordem</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($ordercontents as $ordercontent)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $ordercontent->material_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $ordercontent->type }}</td>
            <td>{{ $ordercontent->oc_weight }}</td>
            <td>{{ number_format($ordercontent->oc_weight * $ordercontent->material_price, 2) }}</td>
            <td>{{ $ordercontent->order_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ $ordercontent->order_name }}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, this would work too but it did work without the <tr> inside the <thead>.